# Avoid typing password every time using NX

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys, nx, freenx

I am running nxserver on a linux box and installed NoMachine Player on laptop.  Every time I connect to nx on the linux box, basically it comes with two steps:

1. SSH to user nx on the linux box
2. On the linux box, the user nx login as the real user

By default, step 1 uses a default dsa key, which is not secure and step 2 is protected by password (you need to type password to login).

I want to avoid typing the password but maintain security.  What I am trying to do is

- For step 1: generate new key pairs.  This is done already by running nxserver --keygen on the linux box.
- For step 2: let nx uses ssh keys to login.

Currently I am stuck at step 2, which I don't know where to put the private key on nx side and how to let nx to use the private key instead of using password authentication.  Anyone can give any hint?  Thanks.

Comment: I'd try posting this at server fault. They might be able to help you more.

Comment: @Griffin, I actually posted on it, but didn't get any response in quite a long time.  I then read the FAQ of serverfault and looks like it is for some large scale network/server problem, so I thought it might not be the right place, then I deleted that post and posted here instead.

Comment: Okay sorry I posted a comment in here that was ment for a different section. I would try posting it again on Serverfault and then on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Griffin, I don't understand what you mean.  Did you mean I should post on Serverfault and StackOverflow?

Comment: If you don't get an answer from Server fault or they say it doesn't belong there.

Comment: @Griffin, I still don't understand your logic.